# How to display on screen the average value of every 1000 samples that come in through the microphone in real-time?

Tags: android, real-time, audio-recording, audio-processing

I want to capture sound from the phone's microphone and display on the screen in real-time the average value of every 1000 samples. This is the code I've got to so far but I'm not getting any values on the screen, it's blank. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Android development so any help will be helpful.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
import android.media.AudioFormat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean recording;  //variable to start or stop recording
    public TextView averagevalue; //text to appear on screen

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        averagevalue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }


   public void Record(){
       AudioRecord recorder;
       short audioData[];
       int bufferSize;

       bufferSize=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT); //get the buffer size to use with this audio record

recorder = new AudioRecord (AudioSource.MIC,44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize); //instantiate the AudioRecorder

recording=true; //variable to use start or stop recording
audioData = new short [bufferSize]; //short array that pcm data is put into.


while (recording) {  //loop while recording is needed
if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) // check to see if the recorder has initialized yet.
if (recorder.getRecordingState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
     recorder.startRecording();  //check to see if the Recorder has stopped or is not recording, and make it record.

else {

recorder.read(audioData,0,bufferSize); //read the PCM audio data into the audioData array
//analyze sound
        int totalAbsValue = 0;
        int samplesquantity = 1000;
        short sample = 0; 
        float averageAbsValue = 0.0f;

     for (int i = 0; i < samplesquantity; i += 1) {
         sample = (short)audioData[i];
         totalAbsValue += Math.abs(sample);
     }
     averageAbsValue = totalAbsValue / samplesquantity;     

     averagevalue.setText(Float.toString(averageAbsValue));                                           

        }//else recorder started

} //while recording

if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) recorder.stop(); //stop the recorder before ending the thread
recorder.release(); //release the recorders resources
recorder=null; //set the recorder to be garbage collected.



   }

}
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

int / int is int.

```
averageAbsValue = (float)totalAbsValue / samplesquantity;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: AH, I forgot: Please use brackets with the if if else to make sure that the else is matched to the right if.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm still not getting anything on the screen after trying this out. Other ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default value for your text view.  That way you can be sure something will be displayed even if your logic isn't being exercised.  You may even want to add some static display content temporarily.  Also check that you are using the correct activity.

Second, you might try calculating the quadratic mean (root mean square) if you want the average signal level of a given sample (1000 points) of data.